# How to correctly connect SQLite with textfields and labels in JavaFX?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making an application with JavaFX, Scene Builder and SQLite. For managing SQLite database I'm using DB Browser

I have 3 fields in SQLite: ID, question, answer

When I press on Button "Add" a method is called and sends text from textaria with question  to question tab in SQLite and text from textaria with answer do the same.

ID is a number and is autoincremented when I add these fields to SQLite

I successfully sent data from my window but I don't understand how to get data from SQlite and set it to label and combobox in my window

[image: Window]

[image: DB Browser]

***QuestController:***

```
package card;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;




public class QuestController implements Initializable {

  @FXML  private TextArea ta_questText, ta_answerText;

  @FXML  private Label lb_numberQuest;

  @FXML
  private ComboBox<?> idQuest;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    //register QuestController in  Context Class
    Context.getInstance().setQuestController(this);

  }

  @FXML
  void addCard(ActionEvent event) {

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    String query = "select * from Cards where ID  = ? and question = ? and 
answer = ?";
Connection connection = DbConnection.getInstance().getConnection();


    try {
  String question = ta_questText.getText();
  String answer = ta_answerText.getText();

  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

  int status = statement.executeUpdate("insert into Cards (question, 
 answer) values ('"+question+"','"+answer+"')");

  if (status > 0) {
    System.out.println("question registered");
      }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

***DbConnection class:***

```
package card;

import org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnection {

  private DbConnection() {

  }

  public static DbConnection getInstance() {

   return new DbConnection();

 }

  public Connection getConnection() {



    String connect_string = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return connection;
  }

}
```

**How can I get all existing ID(numbers) from SQLite and put it to combobox?**

**How can choose a number(ID) and apply number to a label?**

if I choose any number from combobox

**How can I apply text with question and answer from SQLite connected to that number to textarias in my window?**

Comment: I strongly recommend you look into the MCV pattern. You will definitely run into frustration in the future if you continue with your current model.

Comment: You could start by creating a `Question` class that contains your question's `id`, `question` and `answer`. Then create a list of `Question` objects, fill the list from the database, and go from there.

Comment: but user will add questions and answers by himself in application.Text goes to database from textarias.

Comment: Does that mean that having a Controller and it's FXML is bad practice?

Comment: You'll need to query your database by submitting query statements to SQLite via your JDBC connection.  The documentation for your JDBC driver should document which classes you use to create and submit SQL statements.  The results of your queries generally come back to your application as a ResultSet object.  There's nothing wrong with SQLite, but it's not a Java database.  You should consider HSQLCB (http://www.hsqldb.org) which is 100% Java and has a very mature JDBC driver with excellent documentation.

Comment: @scottb JDBC driver is connected successfully and I can write data to SQLite database with text from textarias, but I don't know how to GET data drom SQLite and apply it to my labels or text. There is nothing wrong with connection to SQLite

Comment: JavaFX is a user interface facility.  You should use it only to present data to the user and accept input.  Your JavaFX controller classes, in the ideal circumstance, should not contain and application or "business logic".  The rules for your application should be separated out of the user interface into their own separate classes.

Comment: @kentforth - No, the controller/FXML model is proper. But your **data** should not be tied to either. Generally, you would create a completely separate "datasource" class that interacts with the database. Within that class, you could have methods such as `getQuestion()` and `addQuestion()`. Then your controller can call those methods without needing to know anything about SQL or what type of database you're using.

Comment: You submit SELECT queries to SQLite via JDBC to gather data from the database and return it to your application.  The results of SELECT queries generally come back via JDBC as a `ResultSet` object that you can step through and populate objects in your user interface.

Comment: @Zephyr but I have class DbConnection to communicate with SQLite. Is it wrong approach? By the way, My friend will use this program and he is the only one who will operate all data

Comment: @scottb can you give an example how to choose some field with text from SQLite and apply that text to a label in the Controller?

Comment: Do you know how to write SELECT statements in SQL?  The SQLite documentation for the SELECT statement is found here:  https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: @scottb this is my first experience working with databases and SQLite. I used the code with SELECT from tutorials. I know this is my fault not to learn all theory of SQLite and daatbase, but I have not so much time to learn it. THat's why I try to learn my mistakes by practice

Comment: There is no facility in JavaFX for automatically connecting a GUI object to a database field.  You'll need to create the logic to query the database yourself with SELECT statements.  Then you'll need to have logic to process the results you get from your queries and populate the objects in your GUI with that information.

Comment: @sottb Yes, I know ) but I don't understand how to do that. That's why I need an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the comments in your post, I highly suggest breaking down your codes into layers for better manageability. Good job on starting with your `DbConnection` class. Additionally, JavaFx already setup some layer for you to start on.

These are the:

- **View**: your FXML file that's created on scene builder
- **Controller**: the JFx controller that FXML forces you to use

Now it is up to you to add more layers to manage your code. I will suggest starting with these:

- **Model**: this will be the main data structure you will work on. For starters, maybe you can follow the structure of your database? *Example: `class Card` with fields `id`, `question`, and `answer`.*
- **Persistence**: this Java class will hold your SQL code. This is also responsible for converting the `ResultSet` object to your **model** object.

Then finally, keep in mind that your are working with layers. Make sure that their interactions don't leak.

`View (FXML) <--> Controller + Model <--> Persistence + Model`

To answer your questions:

> How can I get all existing ID(numbers) from SQLite and put it to combobox?

1. Perform an SQL SELECT using your SQLite connection to fetch all the `id`s. (`SELECT id FROM cards` perhaps?)
2. On successful `SELECT` call, iterate through the `ResultSet` object. Each iteration should fetch the data from `id` column, convert it to string (or whatever type your combobox accepts), then add them all. (something like this: `comboBox.getItems().add(id)`)

> How can choose a number(ID) and apply number to a label?
>
> How can I apply text with question and answer from SQLite connected to that number to textarias in my window?

1. Perform an SQL SELECT using your connection, this time add a WHERE clause in the statement to filter results. Since there is a dynamic part in your SQL now, using `PreparedStatement` will be good. *Example: `SELECT id, question, answer FROM card WHERE id=?`*
2. Using the results of the SQL calls, assign them to the proper JFx Components such as labels and text areas.

Comment: thanx for reply! I wll go and  learn MVC pattern and try to apply all crap from SQLite to my labels and text)